# Stop background work of swingworker

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

I have a little problem and I hope that you can help me.

I have a doInBackground that looks something like this:

```
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
{
   someTool.run();
}
```

someTool belongs to a 3rd party library which I should not change and its run method is a long task that runs for a while.

I wanted to know if it's possible to terminate this task from outside?
The usual Thread.Interrupt() mechanism is not good here since I don't have any loop where I can check the flag and terminate the thread, I tried to find an answer but without success, thanks.

Comment: No, it's not possible when 3rd party code doesn't honor `Thread.interrupt()`. If it's really long running call, you can offload it to other JVM. But this would mean you'll need some communication scheme to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with SwingWorker, and instead it has all to do with the specific question, "is it possible to stop `someTool.run()` once it's been started". Your best bet is to ask the folks that support this library, how best to safely and cleanly stop the method once it's been started.

Comment: @Yakov: Understanding how the library responds to an interrupt is essential if you plan to `cancel()` the worker; it may help to identify the library.